# When using yarn-berry, should I apply the unplugged to the git repository when implementing zero-installs?

Tags: yarn-v2, zero-initialization

When using yarn-berry, should I apply the unplugged to the git repository when implementing zero-installs?

As far as I know, in the case of zero-installs, we proceed with `yarn start` immediately after receiving
`git clone` from the git repository.

However, because of the Unplugged Folder, we have to proceed with `yarn installs` inevitably.

Of course, there are ways to put UnpluggedFolder in git repository using git-ignore, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to run zero-installs.

##### When I tried `yarnstart`

```bash
$ yarn start
C:\Users\com\Desktop\zero3\project\.pnp.cjs:25991
      Error.captureStackTrace(firstError);
            ^

Error: Required unplugged package missing from disk. This may happen when switching branches without running unplugged packages must be fully materialized on disk to work).

Missing package: open@npm:8.4.0
Expected package location: C:\Users\com\Desktop\zero3\project\.yarn\unplugged\open-npm-8.4.0-df63cfe5dules\open\
```

##### gitignore

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*

.yarn/*
!.yarn/cache
!.yarn/patches
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/sdks
!.yarn/versions
# !.yarn/unplugged
```